# Google Directory API nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, google-directory-api

I have been trying to make a script in nodejs to take a email and add it to google groups by the api and delleting it after a time i couldn't get it working i have tried everything but could not get it to work any help would be good

thanks in advainc.

Comment: Please post your code snippet and related error you are seeing.

Comment: We'll need some more info before we can post an answer, but npm module `googleapis` has good documentation and this blog might also help: http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/
The guide focuses on google sheets, but the steps are similar